# Chrome 117 update bad print layouts

Tags: google-chrome, printing, media

Anyone see these changes for printing layouts ?

Any good ideas for fixing, simple data tables with default settings are being rendered terribly

Cheers for any tips to resolve

fix overlapping and odd styling problems with printing pdf's

Comment: Hey, have you found any solutions for this ? I am having the same problem

Comment: I am having the same issues. Im starting to think this is a bug in chrome's latest update

Comment: Also having issues with printing - specifically confirmed it was caused by updating from 116 to 117. Our issue was that the page size is appearing incorrectly now

Answer (score 3):

(Unfortunately I don't have the reputation or I would've just added this as a comment.)

Since Chrome 117 we've been having a print issue (short version is that the first page of a print to PDF looked "scaled down" and doesn't take up the entire page like it should).

I've been stumbling my way through as CSS is a weak area of mine, but I found [this specific commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/9a52d7433cfb8c3b15d190aea41d612307cb596f) from the [117 changelog](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/116.0.5845.187..117.0.5938.63?pretty=fuller&n=10000). Honestly I don't understand the half of it but I noticed that the problem we were having is the first page has a container element with 4 child elements that are all `position: absolute`, and this commit seems to touch on that.

The fix we did is hacky, but unfortunately it's what we're going with for now (the 118 beta doesn't seem to fix our issue). We just added the following to the container element:

```
position: relative;
height: 125vh;
```

(The 4 child elements are all `position: absolute`.)

I don't fully understand what specific problems you're having, but hopefully this might give you a start on what to play around with.

Comment: Super helpful!  In my situation all I had to do was set the CSS for print to have position relative.  Like this: ```@media print {
 #mainColumn {
  position: relative !important;
 }
} ```

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with the right border of the table disappearing in Chrome 117.

There is 1 pixel missing when doing autofit calculations with an oversized table with 100% width.

A workaround with a special `<div>` around `<table>` can solve my case.

```
<div style="display:table; width:100%; padding-right:1pt;">
  <table> .. </table>
</div>
```

[table before workaround](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzerw.png)

[table after workaround](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHpNZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug report in Chromium bug tracker that you may want to follow : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1488751&sort=-opened&q=print&can=2

Last comment to date says a fix will be available

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have the rep to add this as a comment or I would have.

As a follow-up to the [answer from Gabe above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77182341/chrome-117-update-bad-print-layouts/77241137#77241137) this seems like it was a bug in Chrome 117 because as of Chrome 119 the behavior has been reverted and the exact fix you proposed which worked in 117 and 118 is no longer needed as of 119 and actually makes the content appear too large (which is actually what you would have expected given this odd fix)